# Refresh Oracle sql developer connection list in program

Tags: oracle, list, connection, refresh

I am a new SQL developer using Oracle sql developer connect to Oracle.

I know how to refresh Table/View list by right click mouse and choose 'Refresh' which will show new tables I just created.

May I ask if is it possible I can do it from program code?
like execute any procedure or any build-in method that can refresh table list by program?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Tod

I tried searching google but I can't get answer,I am feel guilty to ask this Lazy question,but I believe the answer and question will help lots of lazy programmer like me

exec refresh_table_list

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you just need to use your mouse.

If you use the New Table dialog, we will refresh the list for you automatically.

The only other way would be to disconnect and reconnect, but that would be awfully expensive.

Or if you've just created your table, and you want to open it - use the [ctrl+mouse hover click trick.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/sql-developer-describe-versus-ctrlclick-to-open-database-objects/)